# Can't get full width in dropdown menu in css

Tags: html, css

I am creating a college project. I want drop down menu with full width. Although, I don't know why I am getting this output. I have tried many ways, but I can't get proper output.

[output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvGcL.png)

Output that I want is

[output that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHIUu.png)

This is my code.

```css
.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{
                content: " ";
                display: table;
            }
            .clearfix:after{
                clear: both;
            }
            
            .head_nav{
                top: 0;
                position: sticky;
                z-index: 1;
                background-color: #262626;
                margin-bottom: 8px;
            }
            .head_nav a{
                color: #d9d9d9;
                float: left;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            .head_nav a:hover{
                color: white;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            .dropdown {
                float: left;
            }
            .dropdown .menu_button {
                font-size: 16px;  
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                color: white;
                background-color: inherit;
            }
            .menu_dropdown .header {
                background: red;
                padding: 16px;
                color: white;
            }
            .menu_dropdown {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                left: 0;
                z-index: 1;
                background-color: #262626;
            }
            .dropdown:hover .menu_dropdown {
                display: block;
            }
            .menu_dropdown a:hover {
                color: white;
            }
            .dropdowncontainer{
                background-color: inherit;
            }
```

```html
<div class="head_nav clearfix">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="menu_button">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="menu_dropdown">
                        <div class="dropdowncontainer">
                            <a href="#">Register</a>
                            <a href="#">Login</a>
                            <a href="#">Admin</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want this drop down menu width full width and all content left aligned. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your attached code does not produce your result, please provide a snippet that illustrates your problem or include all your code

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz or anything where we can try changing it

Comment: This is link to my code https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G76DKDLR0KP3 @user8351493

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove .dropdown class `float:left` and add  the below given css:

```
.menu_dropdown .dropdowncontainer a{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```css
body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{
            content: " ";
            display: table;
        }
        .clearfix:after{
            clear: both;
        }

        .head_nav{
            top: 0;
            position: sticky;
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: #262626;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
        }
        .head_nav a{
            color: #d9d9d9;
            float: left;
            text-decoration: none;
        }


        .dropdown .menu_button {
            font-size: 16px;  
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            color: white;
            background-color: inherit;
        }
        .menu_dropdown .header {
            background: red;
            padding: 16px;
            color: white;
        }
        .menu_dropdown {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: #262626;
        }
        .menu_dropdown .dropdowncontainer a{
          display:block;
          width:100%;
        }
        .menu_button:hover+.menu_dropdown {
            display: block;
        }
        .menu_dropdown a:hover {
            color: white;
        }
        .dropdowncontainer{
            background-color: inherit;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ecdc7512a9.js"></script>


<div class="head_nav clearfix">
     
     <a href="#">Home</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="menu_button">
                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="menu_dropdown">
                <div class="dropdowncontainer">
                    <a href="#">Register</a>
                    <a href="#">Login</a>
                    <a href="#">Admin</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it show menu event if I hover over Home anchor element.

Comment: Great! You saved my day

Answer (score 0):

please try below code..

```css
.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{
            content: " ";
            display: table;
        }
        .clearfix:after{
            clear: both;
        }

        .head_nav{
            top: 0;
            position: sticky;
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: #262626;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
        }
        .head_nav a{
            color: #d9d9d9;
            float: left;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .head_nav a:hover{
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .dropdown {
            float: left;
            width:100%;
        }
        .dropdown .menu_button {
            font-size: 16px;  
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            color: white;
            background-color: inherit;
        }
        .menu_dropdown .header {
            background: red;
            padding: 16px;
            color: white;
        }
        .menu_dropdown {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: #262626;
        }
        .menu_dropdown a{
          display:inline-block;
          width:100%;
        }
        .dropdown:hover .menu_dropdown {
            display: block;
        }
        .menu_dropdown a:hover {
            color: white;
        }
        .dropdowncontainer{
            background-color: inherit;
        }
```

```html
<div class="head_nav clearfix">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="menu_button">
                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true">i</i>
            </button>
            <div class="menu_dropdown">
                <div class="dropdowncontainer">
                    <a href="#">Register</a>
                    <a href="#">Login</a>
                    <a href="#">Admin</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This brings menu division in new line. I want it to be inline.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end of your css to unfloat the dropdown items and give them full width.

```
.menu_dropdown a {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```